# Server Move - MX Record pointed wrongly

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I am trying to move a site from host A to host B and email is hosted in host C and we would like to retain the same.  I have set the same MX record for both A and B, however when I run a test at

http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=myclientdomainname.com I get an error

failed message send with: failed cx open with: failed socket connect with: Operation now in progress.  Moreover I see that the IP address of the MX records are different when the old host had it (and working fine) and now.  The website, however is functioning properly from the new server.

The old host is nexcess and the new host is bluehost, I think mails are in rackspace.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit:
Just to add more clarity the mx records are mx1.emailsrvr.com and mx2.emailsrvr.com.  Thanks

Comment: Is the MX record pointing to an A record if so did you setup the A record? ie `mx:mail.mydomain.com` `a:mail.mydomain.com:10.10.10.10`

Comment: I am sorry, I am not an expert, I have an A record for my primary domain, can you kindly let me know how I can setup an MX record to point to an A record

Comment: @skv  Where are your nameservers records hosted? At domain seller or the website/server host? Are you using any website control panel?

Comment: The nameservers are hosted in domain host, the website works fine after the change, its just the mx records that arent working.

Comment: Just like how @Shutupsquare pointed, every MX record has to have an A record. So, if your MX record shows up like mail.mydomain.com, then its A record should be resolving to host C Mail server IP address. (http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3amail.mydomain.com&run=toolpage)/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3amail.mydomain.com&run=toolpage

Comment: Thank you both for the help.  As I just added to the question, the mx records are mx1.emailsrvr.com and mx2.emailsrvr.com, since these are different from my own domain, can you guide me how I could setup an A record for this

Comment: It would help if we could have the domain that has the problem.  As the mx records look fine as in they are correct and resolve to some mail server somewhere.

Comment: Right now its pointed to the problematic bluehost server, if you want me to point it to the right one, please let me know and I shall do that.  Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your nameservers is broken: ns1.rhostbh.com is intermittently timing out. This doesn't generally impact users, as the other nameserver will be tried, but a DNS checker will flag it as an error.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I have also tested now and yes what you pointed is a fact, however I have set it up in a reseller panel myself, and  can you suggest any resolution to the issue

Comment: Turns out that the issue was only with the report thanks